# is there any way to sort a datatable alphabetically in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I would like to know if there is any way to sort a datatable in primefaces alphabetically using a custom paginatortemplate or otherwise

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtPaginatorView.cars}" rows="10"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">


    </p:dataTable>
```

[image]

Comment: Why you want to use a custom paginatortemplate? The normal sort function of the primefaces datatable already supports alphabetical sorting: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml If you want to sort the datatable already before it's shown just sort the cars list.

Comment: There's also a sortOrder attribute for the datatable, to set the initial sort of the table in your xhtml.

Comment: I would like to set the paginator to display only elements that start with a letter, for example clicking in "A" button show:  "Audi", "Alfa Romeo".. "B" for Bentley, Buick,etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the [Primefaces Datatable SortBy Attribut](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml)

```
    <p:column headerText="Color" sortBy="#{car.color}">
        <p:inputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
```